# Can I have multiple communication protocols in a Cortex processor?

Tags: controller, protocols, cortex-m, processor

I have to connect a ultrasonic sensor (UART protocol) and a camera which requires another communication protocol to a Cortex M3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Most Cortex-M3 (such as an STM32F1 or 2 for example) have numerous USARTS / UARTS. Depending on your choice of processor they can also have numerous CAN bus, I2C, SPI, Ethernet (some have specific camera interfaces) etc. You just need to choose the right micro-controller for your needs.

You probably also want to consider how much processing power you need, if you need external memory, and whether or not you need floating point maths (If so go for an M4 with FPU).